# howto: Read input and store it in another file

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that reads the highest value from one file and stores it in another. I've read about ifstream and ofstream but how do I let the ofstream store the highest value from the instream in another file? Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct CsvWhitespace : ctype<char> {
static const mask* make_table() {
    static vector<mask> v{classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size};
    v[','] |=  space;  // comma will be classified as whitespace
    return v.data();
}
CsvWhitespace(size_t refs = 0) : ctype{make_table(), false, refs} {}
}    csvWhitespace;

int main() {
string line;
ifstream myfile ("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/log.csv");


ofstream myfile2 ("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/log2.csv");


return 0;
}
auto v = vector<int>{};
myfile.imbue(locale{myfile.getloc(), &csvWhitespace});
copy(istream_iterator<int>{myfile}, istream_iterator<int>{}, back_inserter(v));
myfile2 << *max_element(begin(v), end(v));
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `"C:\Users\Username\Desktop\log.csv"` is wrong. You need to escape the \ character or use / instead.

Comment: Is the file format just a sequence of comma separated integers? And the output a single integer?

Comment: They're both comma separated integers like : 2,271,54,-50,-36,60,13

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy from the one file in the other, without having to worry about the format, by treating them in binary mode. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define bufSize 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *ifp, *ofp;
  char buf[bufSize];
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: %s <soure-file> <target-file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }
  if ((ifp = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
  { /* Open source file. */
    perror("fopen source-file");
    return 1;
  }
  if ((ofp = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL)
  { /* Open target file. */
    perror("fopen target-file");
    return 1;
  }
  while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), ifp) != NULL)
  { /* While we don't reach the end of source. */
    /* Read characters from source file to fill buffer. */
    /* Write characters read to target file. */
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), strlen(buf), ofp);
  }
  fclose(ifp);
  fclose(ofp);
  return 0;
}
```

which was given as an example in IP, [source](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/copy-files-c/). You just need to specify the cmd arguments as the desired files.

Comment: Ok, but I only need to copy the highest value, how do I do that?

Comment: @user4476151 instead of `fwrite()` in the loop, check for the highest value, by using a local variable and copy only the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. [Live example](http://ideone.com/RAkjWP) using `cin` and `cout` rather than files.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct CsvWhitespace : ctype<char> {
    static const mask* make_table() {
        static vector<mask> v{classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size};
        v[','] |= space;  // comma will be classified as whitespace
        return v.data();
    }
    CsvWhitespace(size_t refs = 0) : ctype{make_table(), false, refs} {}
};

int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("log.csv");
    ofstream myfile2("log2.csv");
    auto v = vector<int>{};
    myfile.imbue(locale{myfile.getloc(), new CsvWhitespace{}});
    copy(istream_iterator<int>{myfile}, istream_iterator<int>{}, back_inserter(v));
    myfile2 << *max_element(begin(v), end(v));
}
```

Comment: Does this program copy the highest value or the whole file? I only need the highest value

Comment: Highest value, look at the stdin and stdout in the live example.

Comment: Replace every use of `cin` in this code with your `ifstream` object (input file stream - `myfile` in your code) and every use of `cout` with your `ofstream` object (output file stream - `myfile2` in your code).

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: If you want it to work with your existing code you need to use the names of your file stream objects in place of `cin` and `cout`, so replace `cin` with `myfile` (not with `ifstream` as you've done above) and `cout` with `myfile2` (not with `outstream` as you've done above). You need to replace all occurences, including the `cin` in `cin.getloc()`.

Comment: so like this? Regarding the output do I have to delete it? Because I need what's in the file (myfile) not writing "This is a line.\n"

Comment: You can delete all your original code except the lines that create the `myfile` and `myfile2` objects.

Comment: That's basically right, you just need to delete the closing brace and `return 0` left over from your original code to get something that will compile. I've edited my code here with the correct code, and fixed a bug with how the `CsvWhitespace` instance was passed to the `locale` constructor (it should have been `new`ed instead of a pointer to a global).